# Button with on click doesn't work on iDevices

Tags: jquery, html, mobile-safari

I have this sliding down header which slides down when it is pressed.

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/ygAV2/2/

```
$(document).on("click", 'h1', function() {
    if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('header-down')) {
        $(this).parent().stop().animate({
            height: '100px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 600,
            easing: 'linear'
        }).addClass('header-down');
    } else {
        $(this).parent().stop().animate({
            height: '30px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 600,
            easing: 'linear'
        }).removeClass('header-down');
    }
});



$(document).click(function () {
    if ($(".box_header").hasClass('header-down')) {
        $(".box_header").stop().animate({
            height: '30px'
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 600,
            easing: 'linear'
        }).removeClass('header-down');
    }
});

$(document).on("click", ".box_header", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // This is the preferred method.
    // This should not be used unless you do not want
    // any click events registering inside the div
});
```

The header and the "delete me" button works okay on a computer, but doesn't work on my iPhone and iPad, has any one tried this before?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (should work, tried it on the iOS simulator - no device present):

```
$('h1').on('click touchstart', function() {
    // ... your code 
});
```

Comment: When I do this the slidedown doesn't work on newly added boxes.

Comment: Damn. I'm sorry - no more ideas and no ios device to test :(

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post but something I have found is that Mac OS and iOS doesn't allow you to have click actions unless the corresponding layer is in fact a html button.

I noticed it when I built a site last week and the mobile menu was able to be toggled using a span on Windows and Android devices but Mac OS and iOS didn't toggle the menu.

The second I changed the layer to an actual html button, it worked!

Facepalm at Apple for that!

Answer (score -1):

Try using [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead of `.on` or `.click`:

```
$('h1').live('click', function() {
    // your code goes here...
});
```

Comment: `live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in 1.9.

Comment: I was told .live was deprecated, which is why i have .on?

Comment: Have you tried setting manually `cursor:pointer;` in your css? Another solution may be to use `.on('touchstart', function() { ... });`.

Comment: yes I have tried `cursor:pointer;`and I have tried `.on('click touchstart', function() { ... });`but not just `.on('touchstart', function() { ... });`

Comment: update:

`.on('touchstart', function() { ... });`doesn't work either